# Sequelize not accepting valid moment.js object in where clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following sequelize query:

```
let prms = periods.map((period, index, arr) => {
    if (arr[index + 1]) {
        return sequelize.models.Result.aggregate('value', 'avg', {
            where: {
                createdAt: {
                    $lt: arr[index + 1],
                    $gt: period
                },
                type: hook.params.headers.type,
                entityId: hook.params.headers.entity
            }
        }).catch(err => console.log('err'));
    }
})
```

Now, the `createdAt` property on the where object is causing me this problem:

> error:  Error: Invalid value 1506211200000
>        at Object.escape (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\myProj\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sql-string.js:50:11)
>        at Object.escape (C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\myProj\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:917:22)

Now I don't have any idea where the `1506211200000` number is coming from, both `arr[index + 1]` and `period` are moment.js objects, and I can verify this by doing `console.log(arr[index + 1].isValid(), period.isValid());` which prints `true true`. If  remove the createdAt restriction, there is no issue.

Any idea what is going on here?

NB: I am using Postgres

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert `moment` object to `Date` object using `moment#toDate` method, to use it in sequelize query:

```
...
createdAt: {
  $lt: arr[index + 1].toDate(),
  $gt: period.toDate()
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement on the accepted answer: If you need it to be timezone aware, you will probably need to use the `format` method from the moment object. Like so:

```js
...
where: {
  createdAt: {
    Op.lt: arr[index + 1].format(),
    Op.gt: period.format()
  }
...
}
```

Using the `toDate` method, it will use the local timezone, so you might get seemingly byzantine errors when deploying code to production, as the machine where you're deploying might have a different timezone from your local machine.

You can read further regarding this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone).